# Match word-characters including country-specific letters like öäü

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a JavaScript-Regexp, and I need to match all kind of words.

The SW should be multilingual, and therefore should support special characters like `öÜßêî`...

Is there a regex like `\w`, that matches all of these letters?

Searching for all possible letters, and inserting them via `[\wöäü...]+` is quite inefficient.

And using something like `[^\s]+` isn't possible either, because I have to ensure, that there are no symbols like `§$%,@`... within words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't support unicode properties in any way, you can't include "latin1 letter" in an expression directly and are bound to use ranges. [Latin1-supplement block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29) contains letters in `C0-FF` except two math symbols at `D7` and `F7`, hence the expression is

```
/[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF]+/
```

Note that this only supports west european letters. If you want to match any unicode letter, there's no way with JS regex other than manually enumerating all `Lu/Ll/Lm` ranges from the [unicode database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt).

Comment: This is a nice idea. Do you know how efficient this regex would be?

Comment: @maja: character ranges are pretty efficient.

Comment: notice: I used this regex in the past but noticed problems with russian. I created a custom regex that includes all chars except whitespace or newline that I use but it's a different usecase than here

Answer (score 1):

Then negate those words which you don't want to appear in the string. It will be efficient as allowed number of characters will be more than not allowed number characters.

Like this:

```
[^§$%,@]+ // will not allow these characters but will match others.
```

Comment: I would ran in the same Problem: not allowing any character, that can be part of a word-character: `[+\-\*\/,\?\!=\^²³\\;\(\)\[\]\{\}<>'"...]`

Comment: @maja, this is the only answer. You ***can*** include those characters and negate it.